# How do I set excel format 0.00% to 0.0000 decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, excel-interop

we need to export some data into excel which is fine, data is in percentages and hence I provide

```
cell.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

The data type of exported values is decimal and hence the above format works fine.

but the problem happens when value is `0.00000000000000000`
excel fails to set a format to that and hence when we open the exported excel file it says

> Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.
>   Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part

and all the cells that have value as 0 show a tag on them saying -

> The number in this cell is formatted as text or is preceded by an apostrophe.

When value is something like `0.023443434343` excel formats it as `2.34%` and format is Percentage with 2 decimal places; I am not sure why it is not able to provide format to 0 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it into a double, then format and write it back.  I don't get any errors that way.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim d As Double

d = ws.Range("C14").Value
ws.Range("C14").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
ws.Range("C14").Value = d
```

I'm not clear if your data is already in the worksheet or not. If it is not then put the data into the double from the source.

```
d = Val("0.00000000000000000")
ws.Range("C14").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
ws.Range("C14").Value = d
```

Comment: Really ? surprising! -- is there any explanation to this .. formats well but still shows same error ... So repair error is still there but after repair excel seems alright.

Comment: Not sure why this is exactly.  Excel does some odd things when making assumptions about what you want.  It does it mostly with dates but i've had these issues with percentages as well.

Comment: That error may be coming from something else as i don't get it after saving and reopening my workbook.